# Data Binding, why isn't it working? C# BIng Maps

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-7, bing, pushpin

I can't seem to get my head around this pushpin binding and I need some more help.

I have the follow code to parse from XML and split a coordinate string in Lat, Lon and Alt. What I want to do is to display these points as pushpins on my  bing maps.

I thought that by creating a new object of Geocoordinates in `Location` I could then bind that to my pushpin location, but nothing is displayed.  Where am I going wrong?

```
namespace Pushpins_Itemsource
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            WebClient busStops = new WebClient();
            busStops.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(busStops_DownloadStringCompleted);
            busStops.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.domain/source.xml"));

        }

        void busStops_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
                return;



            var busStopInfo = XDocument.Load("Content/BusStops2.xml");

            var Transitresults = from root in busStopInfo.Descendants("Placemark")
                                 let StoplocationE1 = root.Element("Point").Element("coordinates")
                                 let nameE1 = root.Element("name")

                                 select new TransitVariables

                                     (StoplocationE1 == null ? null : StoplocationE1.Value,
                                              nameE1 == null ? null : nameE1.Value);

        }

        // Add properties to your class
        public class TransitVariables
        {
            // Add a constructor:
            public TransitVariables(string stopLocation, string name)
            {
                this.StopLocation = stopLocation;
                this.Name = name;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StopLocation))
                {
                    var items = stopLocation.Split(',');
                    this.Lon = double.Parse(items[0]);
                    this.Lat = double.Parse(items[1]);
                    this.Alt = double.Parse(items[2]);
                }
            }

            public string StopLocation { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public double Lat { get; set; }
            public double Lon { get; set; }
            public double Alt { get; set; }

        }

        public class TransitViewModel
        {
            ObservableCollection<TransitVariables> Transitresults ;
            public ObservableCollection<TransitVariables> TransitCollection
            {
                get { return Transitresults; }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

XAML looks like this.

```
<my:Map ZoomLevel="6" Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,6,0,0" CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed" LogoVisibility="Collapsed" Name="Map" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456">
    <my:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TransitVariables}" Height="494">
        <my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <my:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}"  />
            </DataTemplate>
        </my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </my:MapItemsControl>
</my:Map>
```

Comment: How are is TransitVariables stored? Is it a property in some class somewhere, and ideally it should be an `ObservableCollection<TransitVariables>`? Your ItemSource needs to bind to a property, not a type.

Comment: `Databinding` - how does it work? :D

Comment: @Alan The locations from an XML that is parsed and then split between lat long and alt. I didnt' realise I needed an observable collection. How would I implement that?

Comment: @Jeremy I have bound text/images to listbox's before so I have a basic idea of Databinding, but I have a lot to learn.

Comment: From the code you've posted, the ItemsSource for MapItemsControl is bound to a type, not a property. Thus it's really not bound to anything.

Comment: @Rhys I wasn't having a go at you I was merely joking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've posted, it looks like the issue is that the ItemsSource for MapsItemsControl is not databound to a collection. It's bound to a type.

Okay, Databinding doesn't really work unless you define a DataContext etc. You're sort of mixing and matching paradigms here. I think it would be good to learn MVVM and Databinding at somepoint, but for now, I think it's okay to just do a quick and dirty approach.

The *easiest* way to get this working is to just assign the ItemSource.

To do this, first name your MapsItemControl, so you can access it in the codebheind.

```
<my:Map ZoomLevel="6" Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,6,0,0" CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed" LogoVisibility="Collapsed" Name="Map" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456">
<my:MapItemsControl x:Name="RhysMapItems" ItemsSource="{Binding TransitVariables}" Height="494">
    <my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <my:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</my:MapItemsControl>
```

Inside your download string complete handler, you should be able to do this:

```
    void busStops_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            return;



        var busStopInfo = XDocument.Load("Content/BusStops2.xml");

        var Transitresults = from root in busStopInfo.Descendants("Placemark")
                             let StoplocationE1 = root.Element("Point").Element("coordinates")
                             let nameE1 = root.Element("name")

                             select new TransitVariables

                                 (StoplocationE1 == null ? null : StoplocationE1.Value,
                                          nameE1 == null ? null : nameE1.Value);

       // This should bind the itemsource properly
       // Should use Dispatcher actually...see below
       RhysMapItems.ItemsSource = Transitresults.ToList();
    }
```

Now, the one caveat here, is that it's very likely that your DownloadStringCompleted handler will be invoked on a different thread than the UI thread.

In which case you'll need to make use of the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() to modify the ItemSource property.

```
this.RootVisual.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( _=> { RhysMapItems.ItemsSource = Transitresults.ToList();});
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I am even more confused. So I dont need my `<my:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}"  />`  Any chance you could show me how I would change my code to make this work?

Comment: Sorry, yes you do need to define your item template. That part is correct. What you are missing is the DataContext which contains the collection with the `TransitVariables` you wish to show.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to clarify for me. I really appreciate it. I will make the changes tonight and see how I go. Fingers crossed.

Comment: I created a new class , added the Observable collection code and then added the rest to my mypage XAMl, but still nothing. I also get `trannies` is never used or assign to

Comment: Ah, well you actually have to load `trannies` with the data you want :) Also to make use of dynamic databinding during runtime, you'll need to look at `INotifyPropertyChange` If your `TransitVariables` is known at startup, then you can skip that part.

Comment: How do I load trannies up with the data I want? I will post my full code and if you find the time could you show me the required changes?

Comment: Okay I've simplified my asnwer.